# handle didFailToLocateUserWithError when user do not allow to use location services

Tags: swift, mapkit

I want to shows user location on map after the button is pressed with code:

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

but if the user do not allow to use location services and press the button the app should prompt him to fix it. I wanted to implement `didFailToLocateUserWithError` mapView delegate method but I don't know how to handle the error. The method is called twice and the errors are:

> Error Domain=MKLocationErrorDomain Code=0 "Location Services Off" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Location Services Off, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Turn on Location Services in Settings > Privacy to allow (null) to determine your current location}

and

> Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check whether the authorisation status is authorised and only execute any functions requiring location usage if the status is authorised. Otherwise either request authorisation or show an alert to user to turn them on. This way you don't need to handle errors, since you are only calling the functions if you actually have authorisation to do so.

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
} else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
} else {
    //show alert
}
```

Keep in mind that the system only displays the built-in authorisation dialog if the authorisation status is not determined. If the user declined authorisation, the built-in dialog will never be shown again, hence in this case, you need to present a custom `UIAlertController` telling the user to turn on authorisation in Settings if they want to use the location-related features of your app.